# React stopPropagation onClick for disabled button with nested elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMXBeN) for an accompanying example related to this question and issue. Related metadata:

- `react 15.6`
- `bootstrap 4.0-beta`
- `font-awesome 4.7`
- Firefox `v55.0`
- Chrome `v60.0`

### Use case

I have a table with some data in it. The user can click a row and edit the row's properties. In one of the columns of every row, there is a button.  When the button is clicked a different action and use case occurs. This action is asynchronous and the user gets feedback on this async operation.
The click on the button is a different action than clicking outside the button's borders (and thus clicking on the '*row*').

### Code example

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isDeleting: false
    };

    this.handleRowClick = this.handleRowClick.bind(this);
    this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleRowClick(event) {
    alert("you clicked the row [use case 1]");
  }

  handleButtonClick(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({isDeleting: true});
    alert("you clicked the button [use case 2]");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr onClick={this.handleRowClick}>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>
              <button disabled={this.state.isDeleting}
                      className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm p-5"
                      type="button"
                      onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>
                {
                  this.state.isDeleting
                  ? <span><i className="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"/> Deleting</span>
                    : "Delete"
                }

              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

### Issue

In the above code example, you can see that whenever the button is clicked, the button gets disabled (*in the real thing, it's disabled until the async operation is finished*). In the example the button is permanently disabled to prove the point.
When you try this out in the codepen with `Firefox`, the UI's behavior is as expected. If you try to click the button while it's disabled, nothing happens: this is the **desired** effect.
However when you try this with `Chrome`, an undesirable effect occurs. First click the button, then when it's disabled, click on either the loading icon (the `<i>` element) or the text `Deleting` which is wrapped inside a `<span>` element. You can see that `handleRowClick` is called (this *is* the issue). There is a reason I've made the padding so huge in the example, because if you click outside the borders of the `<span>` element, but still within the borders of the `<button>`, then nothing happens (which eventually is the desired effect, since it's disabled).

### Question

So this is obviously inconsistent between browsers, which is annoying for the developer. Firefox seems to respect the implicit assumption the developer would have. So would this be a Chrome issue? Or perhaps a bug in React? In any case, our customer cannot wait until either one fixes this issue so a working solution is required while still respecting the customer's wish. Has anyone else encountered this issue before and if yes, what's the best solution?
The only solution I can think of is one that I rather not apply:
Check the `event.target` in the `handleRowClick` callback. However this rises potential maintainability issues. If one of the column's has nested elements, then additional logic need to be added to check what's being clicked on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the click, your button is disabled, so the `onClick` is due to internal `span`.

Add the following CSS style to your child element

```
pointer-events: none;
```

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/CamAnNguyen/pen/MvMzoK) for a working example.